# Difference between firebase auth verifyBeforeUpdateEmail and updateEmail

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

You can use updateEmail with the following workflow:

```js
        await user.updateEmail(newEmail)
        await user.getIdToken()
        await user.sendEmailVerification()
```

and there's also a function `verifyBeforeUpdateEmail`.

These two workflows seems identical to me, but is there any difference?
The documentation lacks examples and explanations of the difference.
Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#verifybeforeupdateemail

Comment: Sorry for my late reply and thank you for kindly guiding me. :)

Answer (score 5):

The [`User.verifyBeforeUpdateEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#verifybeforeupdateemail) method is documented as:

> Sends a verification email to a new email address. The user's email will be updated to the new one after being verified.

So the process here sends a verification email to the new email address. Only once the user clicks the link in that email will their email address be updated **and** the `emailVerified` property of their account set to `true`.

---

The [`user.updateEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updateemail) method is documented as:

> Updates the user's email address.

So when you use `updateEmail`, the user's email address ends up being unverified. If you care about email verification, you'll need to call `sendEmailVerification` again to verify the updates email address. But even if you call `sendEmailVerification` right after updating the email address, the user account will have its `emailVerified` property set fo `false` for a while.

Comment: Thank you for answering! So you mean they are almost identical, except that the separated workflow might have a tiny moment that the user is not emailVerified true, correct?